# I need (horizontal) scrollable list of templated panels !

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

So ... for example I've got some template - panel with edits and data from an object
And now I've got dynamic count of objects and I need dynamic count of panels somewhere :-/

I'm interested in any ideas if there any way to make this frame on WinForms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, turn your "template" into a custom control, for the sake of simplicity, I'm going to refer to it as a `MyControl` that has a `MyData` property.

Now, let's say you need your horizontally scrolling `Panel`, with a `MyControl` per `MyData`, you could do:

```
IEnumerable<MyData> = GetMyData();
foreach( MyData thisData in GetMyData() )
{
    MyControl thisControl = new MyControl();
    thisControl.Dock = Left; // Or right, if you prefer
    thisControl.Value = thisData;
    panel1.Controls.Add( thisControl ); // Where panel1 is a Panel that represents the container for the scrolling-ness
}
```

Obviously, you'll want to tweak that to fit your types, maybe set a few other properties as appropriate.